# Как сделать ограничение переноса текста с нижнего блока, относительно ширины верхнего?

Tags: html, css, текст

[image]

Как сделать ограничение переноса текста с нижнего блока, относительно ширины верхнего?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;

    font-family: Abel, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: 181a1f;
    background-color: #17191e
}

*,
*:before,
*:after
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    margin: 0;
}


/* Container */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Header */

.header_logo {
    margin-top: 43px;
}

/* Intro */
.intro {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.intro_inner {

}

.intro_title {
    line-height: 1 ;
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-size: 176px;
    color: #ffdb00;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;

}

.intro_text {

    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" class="css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abel&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Montreal</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="header_inner">

            <div class="header_logo">
                <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="logo">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="intro">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro_inner">

            <h1 class="intro_title">wake the design</h1>

            <div class="intro_text">Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Уменьшить ширину контейнера, используя `max-width`, также нужно несколько `@media (max-width: ?)` сделать, чтобы на разной ширине экрана тоже всё подкрутить

Comment: @МихаилКамахин неправильно нарисовал, все элементы и так находятся в фиксированном контейнере и не выходят за него, я хочу чтобы блок с текстом и текст внутри него был по ширине верхнего блока с заголовком, а блок заголовка ограничивался текстом внутри него. То есть вот так: https://imgur.com/a/w9Xs4I2

Comment: Да, я и говорю, уменьшите ширину контейнера, в котором находятся эти два элемента: большой текст и маленький текст

Comment: @Kurokkasu оберните `header` и `intro` в один блок

Answer (score 0):

Можно ограничить ширину блока, ширину текста в `h1` и настроить несколько медиа-запросов

```css
body {
    margin: 0;

    font-family: Abel, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: 181a1f;
    background-color: #17191e
}

*,
*:before,
*:after
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    margin: 0;
}


/* Container */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Header */

.header_logo {
    margin-top: 43px;
}

/* Intro */
.intro {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.intro_inner {
  width: 100%;
}

.intro_title {
    line-height: 1 ;
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-size: 176px;
    color: #ffdb00;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;

}

.intro_text {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1200px) {
  .intro_inner {
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 718px) {
  .intro_inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .intro_title {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  .intro_title {
    font-size: 32.7vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" class="css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abel&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Montreal</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="header_inner">

            <div class="header_logo">
                <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="logo">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="intro">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro_inner">

            <h1 class="intro_title">wake the design</h1>

            <div class="intro_text">Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```